# Get argument position given its value in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, posix, arguments

How can I get the position of an argument by using its value?

For example:

```
myScript.sh hello world

echo "$1"
hello
```

How can I get the position of 'hello', which is 1 in this case?

Comment: Yes. Would help if solution is POSIX compliant

Comment: I'm not sure I actually recommend this but: `printf '%s\0' "$@" | awk -vRS='\0' -vfind=hello '$0==find{print NR;exit}'` (all POSIX). Omit exit if there may be multiple matches and you want all of them. You can also find the argument(s)  _containing_ a string with `index($0,find)` or matching it as a regular expression with `$0~find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it wouldn't surprise me if there were quicker, easier ways, something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
pos=0
found=no
for arg ; do
    let pos++
    if [[ "$arg" == "hello" ]] ; then
        found=yes
        break
    fi
done
if [[ "$found" == "yes" ]] ; then
    echo "Found hello at position $pos"
else
    echo "hello not found"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this can work for now, but I hope there is a quicker way as you said.